# How to send an Adaptive card to Compose Box after calling microsoftTeams.tasks.submitTask(data) from botframework

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I'm trying to implement a team Messaging Extensions app which include a compose action, a task module and a bot. The action is defined in the app manifest file to bring up a html page through a task module(step 1), the html page collects user data and uses "microsoftTeams.tasks.submitTask(data)" to submit data to the bot(step 2), then close the dialog(step 3). Once the bot receives the data, it sends an Adaptive card to the compose box(step 4) so the user can post the card to chat.

My question here is how the Step 4 can be implemented in my bot. I am looking at the TeamsActivityHandler.onTeamsTaskModuleSubmit() method, I can see the submitted data, and I can return a TaskModuleResponse object which can be either a text message or an other task module. However I can't find any documentation or code samples to send an Adaptive card to the compose box.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Here is the definition of the action in my app manifest:

```
"composeExtensions": [
    {
        "botId": "b675870e-697f-4672-b4f2-64adafcxxxxx",
        "canUpdateConfiguration": true,
        "commands": [
            {
                "id": "commandId",
                "type": "action",
                "title": "new customer",
                "fetchTask": false,
                "context": [
                    "compose",
                ],
                "taskInfo": {
                    "title": "create new customer",
                    "width": "medium",
                    "height": "medium",
                    "url": "https://fd5b-205-211-178-000.ngrok.io/upload.html"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Please go through the below documentation for your reference:

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/messaging-extensions/what-are-messaging-extensions#action-commands
2. https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/51.teams-messaging-extensions-action